# Does postfix handle legal emails like "test@other"@example.com correctly?

Tags: postfix

The email address "test@other"@example.com is a legal email address.

Lets assume my mail server has domain example.com assigned.

I can successfully sent e-mails to the e-mailaddress from any local mail account on example.com.

If I sent to this mail from any other mail provider, postfix replies incorrectly with `554 5.7.1. <test@other@example.com>: Relay access denied`

(Note the missing escaping of the first at-symbol)

Now my question is, is this a configuration issue or a bug in postfix?

Comment: AFAIK postfix handles these correctly. Look at your mail logs to see what might be going on. You omitted most of the log entries for this message.

Comment: well, there are no log entries which could be of any use. The log shows just the connection, then the rejection with the above reason.

Comment: OK, how about the rest of the log entry, a part of which you posted?

Comment: It turns out, that postfix interprets emails with an "at"  in the local part as so-called sender-specified routing.

Comment: OK, wow, that's crazy. I haven't heard of anyone seriously doing anything like that since the 80s. Maybe the early 90s.